# How do i make electron rebuild work so that i can use sqlite3?

Tags: electron

I am trying to create an app that uses `sqlite3` however in order for it to work i need to **install and run** `electron-rebuild` while `knex` act's as my middleware.

i have managed to install all the npm packages `knex, sqlite3 and electron-rebuild` using the following commands:

`npm install electron-rebuild --save-dev`

`npm install sqlite3 knex`

in my `package.json` **scripts**  i have include:

```
  "scripts": {
    "rebuild": "electron-rebuild -f -w sqlite3",
    "start": "electron .",
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
```

However when i run: `npm run rebuild`
I get:

```
> tarik@1.0.0 rebuild /home/alexander/Desktop/tarik
> electron-rebuild -f -w sqlite3


An unhandled error occurred inside electron-rebuild
Unable to find electron-prebuilt's version number, either install it or specify an explicit version

Error: Unable to find electron-prebuilt's version number, either install it or specify an explicit version
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/alexander/Desktop/tarik/node_modules/electron-rebuild/lib/src/cli.js:81:19)
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
    at /home/alexander/Desktop/tarik/node_modules/electron-rebuild/lib/src/cli.js:8:71
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at __awaiter (/home/alexander/Desktop/tarik/node_modules/electron-rebuild/lib/src/cli.js:4:12)
    at /home/alexander/Desktop/tarik/node_modules/electron-rebuild/lib/src/cli.js:70:8
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/alexander/Desktop/tarik/node_modules/electron-rebuild/lib/src/cli.js:146:4)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:702:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:713:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:612:32)
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 255
npm ERR! tarik@1.0.0 rebuild: `electron-rebuild -f -w sqlite3`
npm ERR! Exit status 255
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the tarik@1.0.0 rebuild script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/alexander/.npm/_logs/2019-09-01T12_36_46_896Z-debug.log
```

i am using **ubuntu18.04**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Figured out how to fix this to help someone else in future here is what i did:**

- You need to install electron in your current project. I was using globally installed electron...also don't forget to save the dependency. If not saved you'll get errors when rebuilding.
- i was running the `electron-rebuild` wrongly to run electron rebuild:

**On macOS and linux**

> Every time you run "npm install", run this:

```
   ./node_modules/.bin/electron-rebuild
```

**On Windows**

> On Windows if you have trouble, try:

```
 .\node_modules\.bin\electron-rebuild.cmd
```

https://electronjs.org/docs/tutorial/using-native-node-modules